# Usage of access token in a given javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am trying to use [this](https://github.com/normalhuman/EnhancedCloseReview) script on my browser (google chrome). The developer of the script says we need the "Access Token" provided in the link he gives. I use Tampermonkey and tried to edit the file by putting the access token, but I didn't manage to make the script to work properly. It also seems that the access token keeps changing. How can I make this script work properly?

The code is below:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Enhanced Close Review
// @namespace   https://github.com/normalhuman/
// @description Adds one-click votes cast via the API
// @match       *://*.askubuntu.com/review/close/*
// @match       *://*.mathoverflow.net/review/close/*
// @match       *://*.serverfault.com/review/close/*
// @match       *://*.stackapps.com/review/close/*
// @match       *://*.stackexchange.com/review/close/*
// @match       *://*.stackoverflow.com/review/close/*
// @match       *://*.superuser.com/review/close/*
// @grant       none
// @run-at      document-end
// @version     15.10.2
// ==/UserScript==

var token = 'YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN';
// obtain at https://stackexchange.com/oauth/dialog?client_id=5730&scope=no_expiry,write_access&redirect_uri=https://stackexchange.com/
var apiKey = 'SdXjf2ahk8btsT*QqXqkxA((';
window.setInterval(main, 200);


function main() {
  var link = document.querySelector('.reviewable-post-stats a');
  if (link && !link.classList.contains('processed')) {
    link.classList.add('processed');
    var site = window.location.hostname.split('.')[0];
    var qId = document.querySelector('.question-hyperlink').href.split('/')[4];
    var filter = '!w--m02m_t.3eBhW6iq';
    var request = 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/'+qId+'/close/options?site='+site+'&key='+apiKey+'&filter='+filter+'&access_token='+token;
    $.ajax({url: request, dataType: 'json', method: 'GET'}).done(function(data) {
      var items = data.items;
      var textOptions = ['unclear', 'too broad', 'opinion'];
      var fullText = ["unclear what you're asking", "too broad", "primarily opinion-based"];
      var options = [items[2].option_id, items[3].option_id, items[4].option_id];
      var offtopic = items[1].sub_options;
      for (var i = 0; i < offtopic.length-1; i++) {
        if (offtopic[i].option_id) {
          fullText.push(offtopic[i].description.replace(/<\/?\w*>/ig, ''));
          textOptions.push(offtopic[i].description.replace(/\b(questions?|asking|seeking|this|it|is|on|to|us|by|a|an|the|about)\b|<\/?\w*>/ig, '').slice(0,20).toLowerCase()+'…');
          options.push(offtopic[i].option_id);
        }
        else {
          break;
        }
      }
      addLinks(options, textOptions, fullText);
    });
  }
}


function addLinks(options, textOptions, fullText) {
  var links = document.querySelector('.reviewable-post-stats a').parentElement;
  var votelink = vlink('downvoteQ', 'downvote', 'downvote the question');
  votelink.onclick = downvote;
  links.appendChild(votelink);    
  for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    votelink = vlink('CV'+options[i], textOptions[i], fullText[i]);
    votelink.onclick = function(e) {
      castClose(e.currentTarget.id.slice(2));
      var actions = document.querySelector('.review-actions').children;
      actions[actions.length-1].click();
    };
    links.appendChild(votelink);
  }
}


function castClose(opt) {
  var site = window.location.hostname.split('.')[0];
  var qId = document.querySelector('.question-hyperlink').href.split('/')[4]; 
  var request = 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/'+qId+'/flags/add';
  var payload = {site: site, id: qId, option_id: opt, key: apiKey, access_token: token, preview: false, filter: '!)V)M6IkwOn1'};
  $.post(request, payload, handle, 'json');
}


function downvote() {
  var site = window.location.hostname.split('.')[0];
  var qId = document.querySelector('.question-hyperlink').href.split('/')[4]; 
  var request, payload = {site: site, id: qId, key: apiKey, access_token: token, preview: false, filter: '!)V)M6IkwOn1'};  
  var link = document.getElementById('downvoteQ');
  if (link.textContent === 'downvote') {
    request = 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/'+qId+'/downvote';
    $.post(request, payload, handle, 'json');
    link.textContent = 'undo downvote';
  }
  else {
    request = 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/'+qId+'/downvote/undo';
    $.post(request, payload, handle, 'json');
    link.textContent = 'downvote';
  }
}


function handle(data) {
  console.log(data);
  if (data.error_message) {
    window.alert(data.error_message);
  }
}


function vlink(eId, eText, eTitle) {
  var e = document.createElement('a');
  e.id = eId;
  e.textContent = eText;
  e.title = eTitle;
  e.style.display = 'block';
  e.style['margin-top'] = '8px';
  return e;
}
```

Comment: Please share sample code

Comment: @sunijt I added the code (I don't know if this is what you meant... hope it was).